# How to filter collection values which are strings based on a specific regex?

Tags: java, jxls

I have a collection of string arrays which I write to Excel file using jXLS library. But I want only strings that match a regex to be written onto the excel file.

Comment: Nice plan, good for you.

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I can change attributes in the Excel Template (namely jx:each command) I am using to translate to the Excel file. I came across an attribute called "select" within the jx:each command, but not sure how to use it properly.

Answer (score 0):

it could be done using java 8 stream api and java.util.regex.Pattern.

for example:

```
    String pattern = "\\d.+";
    Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);


    List<Object> words = Arrays.asList("abc",1.0d,"123","a2c","111",2.3d);

    List<String> filteredWords = words.stream()
            .filter(object->object.getClass()==String.class) //accept only strings
            .map(obj->obj.toString()) // map object to string
            .filter(word->r.matcher(word).matches())
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(filteredWords); // [123, 111]
```

Comment: I have an array of objects which is a collection of string and doubles. I intend to filter that array, removing elements whose string value doesn't match the regex and then write the filtered collection onto the excel file.

Comment: assuming that you have a List<Objects>. you could filter those elements from the stream pipeline. I've edited the answer and gave you another example

Comment: I am looking for a solution where I can change attributes in the Excel Template (namely jx:each command) I am using to translate to the Excel file. I came across an attribute called "select" within the jx:each command, but not sure how to use it properly.